# Vuetify tooltip doesn't show up in the DOM

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When pasting the [docs' example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips) in my component's template:

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
  <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
    <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Button</v-btn>
  </template>
  <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

... I get this in the DOM:

```
<span data-v-26084dc2="" class="v-tooltip v-tooltip--top"></span>
```

This is how I import `Vuetify` in my main.js:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Using `Vue 2.5.17` and `Vuetify 1.3.15`

Comment: but the provided documentation is for `2.x` version

Comment: Oops... Docs for `1.x` aren't available anymore? `2.x` requires Vue Cli 3 which I don't want to install

Comment: `v-slot` was introduced in Vue 2.6.0. You'll need to use the older slot syntax with 2.5.17. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax

Comment: Thanks. Still doesn't work using `slot` instead of `v-slot` though

Answer (score 1):

> v-slot was introduced in Vue 2.6.0. You'll need to use the older slot
> syntax with 2.5.17 and use it directly on <v-btn> element

[vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Deprecated-Syntax)

> slot attribute can also be used directly on a normal element

```
<v-tooltip bottom>
   <v-btn slot="activator" color="primary" dark>Button</v-btn>
   <span>Tooltip</span>
</v-tooltip>
```